# Javafx tableview changelistener changes to often

Tags: java, css, javafx, changelistener

I want to color the rows in my table depending on the the state. After a search I found this [Formatting Rows in a JavaFX TableView Using CSS Pseudo Classes](https://rterp.wordpress.com/2015/04/11/atlas-trader-test/).

I tried to implement it for my purpose. It also works, but if I scroll the color will change back to the default one.
What am i doing wrong?

```
@FXML
private void initialize(){

    PseudoClass online = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("online");
    PseudoClass offline = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("offline");
    PseudoClass unknown = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("unknown");

    //Set a rowFactory for the table view.
    overviewTable.setRowFactory(tableView -> {
            TableRow<State> row = new TableRow<>();
            ChangeListener<String> changeListener = (obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                System.out.println("1: " + obs + " : " + oldValue + " : " + newValue);
                row.pseudoClassStateChanged(online, newValue.equals("online"));
                row.pseudoClassStateChanged(offline, newValue.equals("offline"));
                row.pseudoClassStateChanged(unknown, newValue.equals("unknown"));
            };

            row.itemProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                System.out.println("2: " + obs + " : " + oldValue + " : " + newValue);
                if (oldValue != null) {
                    oldValue.stateProperty().removeListener(changeListener);
                }
                if (newValue != null) {
                    newValue.stateProperty().addListener(changeListener);
                    row.pseudoClassStateChanged(online, newValue.equals("online"));
                    row.pseudoClassStateChanged(offline, newValue.equals("offline"));
                    row.pseudoClassStateChanged(unknown, newValue.equals("unknown"));
                } else {
                    row.pseudoClassStateChanged(online, false);
                    row.pseudoClassStateChanged(offline, false);
                    row.pseudoClassStateChanged(unknown, false);
                }
            });
            return row;
        });
}
```

CSS:

```
.table-row-cell:unknown{
-fx-background-color: blue;
}

.table-row-cell:online{
-fx-background-color: #2EAB15;
}

.table-row-cell:offline{
-fx-background-color: #BB0000;
}

.table-row-cell .text{
-fx-fill: white;
}
```

Comment: "but if I scroll the color will change back to the default one."  What do you mean by this?  Are the pseudo-classes being changed (IE: are you getting syso's)?  Are the pseudo-classes still the same but the colors are just changing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is right here in the listener to the `item` property:

```
if (newValue != null) {
    newValue.stateProperty().addListener(changeListener);
    row.pseudoClassStateChanged(online, newValue.equals("online"));
    row.pseudoClassStateChanged(offline, newValue.equals("offline"));
    row.pseudoClassStateChanged(unknown, newValue.equals("unknown"));
```

Here `newValue` is a object of type `State`. It's unlikely that `equals` is overridden in a way that returns `true`, if a `String` is passed (and I'd advise never implementing `equals` in such a way).

You should instead pass the new value to the listener to trigger an update as if the value of the `state` property had changed:

```
if (newValue != null) {
    newValue.stateProperty().addListener(changeListener);
    changeListener.changed(null, null, newValue.getState());
```

or alternatively compare to the `state` property (which violates the DRY principle though):

```
if (newValue != null) {
    newValue.stateProperty().addListener(changeListener);
    row.pseudoClassStateChanged(online, newValue.getState().equals("online"));
    row.pseudoClassStateChanged(offline, newValue.getState().equals("offline"));
    row.pseudoClassStateChanged(unknown, newValue.getState().equals("unknown"));
```

---

I assume here that the `State` class contains a `getState()` method returning the content of the `state` property. If this is not the case all calls to that method need to be replaced with `stateProperty().getValue()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works now as expected